# Cannot navigate to my end point URL on ASP.NET Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, iis, windows-10

I'm trying to re-install a legacy ASP.NET Web application.  It is old code and I realize that I need to redo it using ASP.NET Core.  My machine was automatically rebuilt by Microsoft's December update and I lost all my programs.  I'm having trouble re-installing a legacy REST Server.  The clients are iPhone Apps, and I don't want to redo them now.

My machine environment is now:

```
  Windows 10 Enterprise
  Version: 1903
  Installed on: 12/11/2019
  OS build: 18362.535
  Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.2
```

My end point URL should be: "http://www.cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService/GetData".

but it no longer works. I am getting a 404 response in my Chrome browser.  The screen shows:

[image]

My complete server code is:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class TrinService : WebService {
  [OperationContract]
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData")]
  [WebMethod]
  public string GetData() {
    try {
      var nyseTrin = 0.00M;
      var msg = string.Format("{0}", nyseTrin);
      return msg;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return "GetTrinData Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

I then re-loaded the project as Administrator and did a Publish.  The browser appeared with:

[image]

and when I click on Invoke, I get:

[image]

So far so good.  However, when I try my original end point URL:

"http://www.cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService/GetData"

I still get error 404.0.

Max, I appreciate you sticking with me.

Charles

Comment: Try the address `http://www.cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService/GetTrinData` and if necessary rename the method name according.

Comment: Thanks  Max for your reply.  I did as you asked (See my revisions above) and it still does not work.  Now I'm very worried.

Comment: The error reported on xml is about *favicon.ico* not the endpoint.The entire url is `http://bigsur:80/favicon.ico`. Try to search for the cypresspoint. Try also to navigate to `http://www.cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService.asmx`and click the *GetTrinData* to see if the endpoint exist.

Comment: I show the navigation to http://www.cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService.asm above.  It works, as well as GetTrinData .  Somethings else is wrong.

Comment: Try the `http://cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService/GetTrinData` without the www above

Comment: Hi "Max".  I changed the method name from "GetTrinData" to "GetData" as you suggested.
As you can see by my edits above, it only works with IIS Express (Google Chrome).
My original end point URL (http://www.cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService/GetData) fails,
with or without "www".

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the *Invoke* button trigger a **POST** request instead of a **GET** request, consequently you **CANNOT** use the browser to test the method.

I made the connection using Postman sending a **POST** request

[image]

Same result if I add the *service reference* on a Visual Studio project

[image]

If you want

Comment: Please see my revised edits above.  We are getting close, but my original end point URL still gives error 404.

Comment: You mistake the `cipresspoint.com` namespace with the **URL** `http://bigsur/TrinREST/TrinService/GetData`. If you test the application on your **local dev machine** and you want to reach the www.cypresspoint.com you must edit the file hosts on `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and add the entry: `127.0.0.1 www.cypresspoint.com` feel free to replace 127.0.0.1 with bigsur if is another machine.

Comment: I showed what occurred when I did a Publish.  I publish to "bigsur" . This is the same a "localhost".  If I replace "bigsur" with the fully qualified domain  name: "http://www.cypresspoint.com/TrinREST/TrinService.asmx" it works.  You can try this URL yourself.  It's on the internet.  This does not answer my question. The original end point URL still does not work.